# What is best practice for large amounts of options in an HTML form?

Tags: forms, layout, checkboxes

I inherited an old web app, which includes an HTML form. This form has a large list of checkboxes for a yes/no on selecting counties to receive updates about. 
[image: Screenshot]

Obviously this is not best practice, because you can't even see the whole list (72 options, plus a select all).

Are checkboxes laid out in a grid the most user friendly way to present this information? I have also considered a map with the counties labeled, and the ability to toggle counties on/off.

Any input on this is appreciated.

Comment: Is there visual feedback that happens once they select? Do you expect users to select a lot of countries? or just a few?

Comment: Users tend to select 2-3 counties or all of the counties. When they select one, the box is checked currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know who your users are but chances are, they won't be able to find all countries they are interested in on a map. So while this might look great, it's probably not the best solution.

I would recommend a searchable mutli select box like the ones many libraries provide.
There users can start typing the names of countries they are interested in and add them to a list of choices.

An example of this would be the multiple select input [Choices.js](https://joshuajohnson.co.uk/Choices/):
[image]

If you are happy with the usability of this but still like your map idea, maybe you could combine both.

Comment: I think that the multiple input select demo you provided will likely be the best way to proceed. I had doubts about the map, but wasn't sure how else to present so many options.